# R1Soft MySQL Failed to perform discovery on database instance

Tags: mysql, backup, r1soft

I am using R1Soft (5.8.1) for file backups on a few servers and have tonight been trying to setup a MySQL backup - I installed the driver etc and am setting up the policy but am getting an error.

```
Failed to perform discovery on database instance '123'
Database instance discovery error
Error setting up proxy connection
Error could not connect to mysql instance
```

My username etc is correct so I am authenticating fine (I know this as I was getting a different error previously relating to hostname which I had to rectify using "Use Alternate Host Name/IP").

I did a search for the error but am not getting anything useful for that message - I found an entry at http://wiki.r1soft.com/display/kb3/Known+Issues+affecting+upgrades+to+Server+Backup+Manager+5.6.x+(post+release) which is the same message but it is related to upgrades and also the fix is to ensure agent and server are running the same version and they are in this instance.

The log files are showing:

```
2014-11-26 21:52:17,533 INFO   - AGENT(MYSQL_IP): Agent Version 5.8.1.38
2014-11-26 21:52:17,535 INFO   - AGENT(MYSQL_IP): Connection authenticated; Waiting for command.
2014-11-26 21:52:17,576 INFO   - AGENT(MYSQL_IP): Executing get device list request...
2014-11-26 21:52:17,576 INFO   - AGENT(MYSQL_IP): Discovering devices available for replication ...
2014-11-26 21:52:17,972 INFO   - TASK(NONE): Starting proxy to agent(MYSQL_IP) -> R1SOFT_IP:3306 on port 4306
2014-11-26 21:52:52,144 INFO   - TASK(NONE): Shutting down proxy server on port 4306
2014-11-26 21:52:52,146 INFO   - TASK(NONE): Proxy server on port 4306 stopped.
2014-11-26 21:52:52,972 ERROR  - Failed to perform discovery on database instance '123'
com.r1soft.backup.server.facade.DatabaseException: Failed to perform discovery on database instance '123'
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.facade.DatabaseFacade.discoverDatabaseInstance(DatabaseFacade.java:58)
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.web.policy.AddDatabaseInstanceWindow.onValidateDataDirWillBeBackedUp(AddDatabaseInstanceWindow.java:865)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2726)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2654)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:136)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.process0(EventProcessingThreadImpl.java:534)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.run(EventProcessingThreadImpl.java:461)
Caused by: com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.WorkerException: Database instance discovery error
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.db.mysql.MySQLInstanceDiscoveryWorker.run(MySQLInstanceDiscoveryWorker.java:121)
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.facade.DatabaseFacade.discoverDatabaseInstance(DatabaseFacade.java:51)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.WorkerException: Error setting up proxy connection
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.AgentProxyWorker$AgentSocketProxyServer.acceptNewConnection(AgentProxyWorker.java:340)
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.AgentProxyWorker$AgentSocketProxyServer.run(AgentProxyWorker.java:405)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.WorkerException: Error could not connect to mysql instance
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.AgentProxyWorker$AgentSocketProxyServer.getNewAutenticatedAgentSocket(AgentProxyWorker.java:305)
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.AgentProxyWorker$AgentSocketProxyServer.access$1100(AgentProxyWorker.java:123)
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.AgentProxyWorker$AgentSocketProxyServer$AgentPipe.<init>(AgentProxyWorker.java:469)
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.AgentProxyWorker$AgentSocketProxyServer.acceptNewConnection(AgentProxyWorker.java:338)
        ... 2 more
2014-11-26 21:56:59,892 ERROR  - GlobalUpdater failed to update properly
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.web.GlobalUpdater$GlobalUpdaterThread.updateCharts(GlobalUpdater.java:1002)
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.web.GlobalUpdater$GlobalUpdaterThread.doUpdates(GlobalUpdater.java:755)
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.web.GlobalUpdater$GlobalUpdaterThread.run(GlobalUpdater.java:639)
2014-11-26 21:57:04,891 ERROR  - GlobalUpdater failed to update properly
java.lang.NullPointerException

        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2654)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:136)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.process0(EventProcessingThreadImpl.java:534)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.run(EventProcessingThreadImpl.java:461)
Caused by: com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.WorkerException: Database instance discovery error
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.db.mysql.MySQLInstanceDiscoveryWorker.run(MySQLInstanceDiscoveryWorker.java:121)
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.facade.DatabaseFacade.discoverDatabaseInstance(DatabaseFacade.java:51)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.WorkerException: Error setting up proxy connection
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.AgentProxyWorker$AgentSocketProxyServer.acceptNewConnection(AgentProxyWorker.java:340)
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.AgentProxyWorker$AgentSocketProxyServer.run(AgentProxyWorker.java:405)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.WorkerException: Error could not connect to mysql instance
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.AgentProxyWorker$AgentSocketProxyServer.getNewAutenticatedAgentSocket(AgentProxyWorker.java:305)
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.AgentProxyWorker$AgentSocketProxyServer.access$1100(AgentProxyWorker.java:123)
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.AgentProxyWorker$AgentSocketProxyServer$AgentPipe.<init>(AgentProxyWorker.java:469)
        at com.r1soft.backup.server.worker.AgentProxyWorker$AgentSocketProxyServer.acceptNewConnection(AgentProxyWorker.java:338)
        ... 2 more
```

Anyone any idea what might be the issue?